# How to Calculate Voltage across R2 for any Value of R1, R2, and Frequency?

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, analysis

[image][image]

I know this is really simple, but I'm really new to electronics, so please bear with me.

CircuitLab said that the voltage across R2 was -14.24 dbV, given the component values shown and a source frequency of 707.9 hz. I was unable to obtain this same answer by the circuit analysis methods I have been taught so far, so please show me the math necessary to get this answer. Thanks for your time.

--A newbie.

also I can reply with the bode plot if you need to see that for some reason.

Comment: You need to show us all of your work, using the "circuit analysis methods I have been taught". We won't do your homework for you.

Comment: What methods? We can help if we have some idea what analysis tools you are comfortable using. Otherwise, all we do is throw mud against the wall in hopes some of it sticks.

Comment: Derive the transfer function.

Comment: I wrote out my (faulty) logic in the image I added to the original post. If you want me to crunch the numbers again, say so and I will add another image with those calculations. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Andy

After googling what a transfer function is, I think I was trying to derive such a function, but failed. If anyone wishes to show me how to do this, I would be grateful.

Side note: I was told by my professor not to read / study the textbook that this circuit originally comes from because "it was too advanced." That's why I'm asking for help here, rather than getting help from them.

Comment: If you haven't been taught how to derive a TF then your prof is asking too much from you.

Comment: Tip: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and **Save and Insert** on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if we are not looking for the transient behavior of the circuit we can use the complex method to find the answer.

First, we can find the current trough \$\text{R}_2\$ using the current divider formula:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{I}_{\text{R}_2\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\frac{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_2+\text{R}_2}\cdot\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\frac{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_2+\text{R}_2}\cdot\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\frac{1}{\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{j}\omega\text{C}\text{j}\omega\text{L}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{C}\text{R}_2}\cdot\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\frac{1}{1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2+\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}\cdot\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\left|1\right|}{\left|1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2+\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}\right|}\cdot\frac{\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\right)^2}}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|}
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

For the input impedance we can write:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}&=\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1+\left(\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\space\text{||}\space\text{j}\omega\text{L}_2+\text{R}_2\right)\\
\\
&=\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1+\frac{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\left(\text{j}\omega\text{L}_2+\text{R}_2\right)}{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_2+\text{R}_2}\\
\\
&=\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1+\frac{\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\left(\text{j}\omega\text{L}_2+\text{R}_2\right)}{\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{j}\omega\text{C}\text{j}\omega\text{L}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{C}\text{R}_2}\\
\\
&=\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2+\text{L}_2\omega\text{j}}{1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2+\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}\\
\\
&=\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2+\text{L}_2\omega\text{j}}{1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2+\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}\cdot\frac{1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2-\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}{1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2-\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}\\
\\
&=\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1+\frac{\left(\text{R}_2+\text{L}_2\omega\text{j}\right)\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2-\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}\right)}{\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2-\text{C}\text{L}_2\text{R}_2\omega^2-\text{C}\text{R}_2^2\omega\text{j}+\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)\text{L}_2\omega\text{j}+\text{C}\text{L}_2\text{R}_2\omega^2}{\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2+\left(\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)\text{L}_2-\text{C}\text{R}_2^2\right)\omega\text{j}}{\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2}{\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\right)^2}+\frac{\left(\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)\text{L}_2-\text{C}\text{R}_2^2\right)\omega\text{j}}{\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\underbrace{\text{R}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2}{\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\right)^2}}_{=\space\Re\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)}+\left\{\underbrace{\text{L}_1\omega+\frac{\left(\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)\text{L}_2-\text{C}\text{R}_2^2\right)\omega}{\left(1-\text{C}\text{L}_2\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\text{C}\text{R}_2\omega\right)^2}}_{=\space\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)}\right\}\cdot\text{j}
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

Where \$\left(\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta\right):=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.

So, for the absolute value of the input impedance we get:

$$\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)+\Im^2\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)}\tag3$$

And we can see that:

$$\text{V}_{\text{R}_2\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_2\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\cdot\text{R}_2\tag4$$

---

Applying all the above to your circuit, we get:

$$\text{V}_{\text{R}_2\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\approx0.13585\space\text{V}\tag5$$

The exact answer is:

```
12500000000Sqrt[2/((10000+50112241Pi^2)(250000000000000000+50112241Pi^2(50112241Pi^2-999990000)))]
```